# Expected end of statement VBA error

Tags: excel, vba, interpolation, bloomberg

I hope you're all doing well!

A quick but tricky question (at least for me)
I have a code that interpolates values according to dates. Basically I want to insert the interpolation value to a cell in the main workbook in the sheet "Deals". 
BInterpol is a function that works with a program installed in my computer. In the function, I take dates( D4:D18) linked to values (E4:E18), the following argument is the date that is located in another workbook and sheet and then linear is the method of interpolation. When I write the code below, it gives me Expected end of statement error and it highlights Linear. Any idea what needs to be change so it works ? (I want to make so that the formula is written in the cell needed so the interpolation is done there)

```
wb2.Sheets("Deals ").Range("V" & x).Value = "=BInterpol('INTERP'!D4:D18,'INTERP'!E4:E18," & wb1.Sheets("New").Range( "I" & j) & " , " Linear " )"
```

Comment: You need to surround `Linear` with &s

Comment: Thanks everybody,
It took no time to resolve my error. I put two pairs of " around Linear and it solved it ( "" LINEAR ""). I'm sure your answers work as well. Thank you very much, I appreciate it !

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.Formula` and concatenate the `Linear` variable to the string with `&` as mentioned in the comments:

```
wb2.Sheets("Deals MTL").Range("V" & x).Formula = "=BInterpol('OIS INTERP'!D4:D18,'OIS INTERP'!E4:E18," & wb1.Sheets("NewTrades").Range( "I" & j) & "," & Linear ")"
```

Depending on what exactly is `Range("I" & j)` you may be interested in getting its address and not its value:

```
wb2.Sheets("Deals MTL").Range("V" & x).Formula = "=BInterpol('OIS INTERP'!D4:D18,'OIS INTERP'!E4:E18," & _ 
                        wb1.Sheets("NewTrades").Range("I" & j).Address & _
                        "," & Linear ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it !

```
wb2.Sheets("Deals").Range("V" & x).Value = "=BInterpol('INTERP'!D4:D18,'INTERP'!E4:E18," & wb1.Sheets("New").Range( "I" & j) & " , "**"** Linear **"**" )"
```

The Linear needed two pairs of " for some reason ( don't know why, but that solved it.